# Centering a div inside of a CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am learning to write HTML/CSS/JS and I am creating some mock websites to learn as I go.  I started venturing into CSS Grid and am struggling to center align horizontally and vertically an item within a grid box.  I find Grid very powerful in creating layouts and for some reason I am failing to understand this portion.  I want to center the `head-content-container` in the header.

In doing research I found [THIS](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) website and [THIS](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/css/cheatsheets/box-alignment) one.  I see they suggest using justify-self:center; and align-self:center; but for some reason I am not able to get it to work.  It is possible that I have another issue that I do not quite understand.  [Here](https://github.com/mtallerico1/Portfolio) is a link to my github repo and below is a snippet of my code.  Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

```
     <body>
        <nav class="main-nav-wrapper">
            <div class="nav-logo-wrapper">
                <img class="nav-logo" src="img\T-Portfolio_Logo-02.svg" alt="Bolt Development Logo">
            </div>       
        </nav>
        <div class="grid-wrapper">
            <header class="main-header">
                <div class="head-content-container">
                    <h1>Bolt Development</h1>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
```

EDIT:  Forgot to add HTML snippet.

```
.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); 
    grid-template-rows: 500px 500px 500px 500px 200px;
    grid-template-areas: "head head head"
                         "main main main"
                         "portfolio_1 portfolio_2 portfolio_3"
                         "portfolio_4 portfolio_5 portfolio_6"
                         "footer footer footer";
}

.main-header {
    grid-area: head;
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/1000/800/tech);
    background-size: cover;
    grid-column: 1/4;
    color: white;
}

.main-nav-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr); 
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #191919;
}

.nav-logo-wrapper {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    padding: .5em;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.nav-logo {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.head-content-container {
    grid-area: head;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, an html snippet accompanying the provided css would help getting better response.

Comment: Added now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out my own question.  I ended up setting the header to display flex and aligning the content.

```
.main-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/1000/800/tech);
    background-size: cover;
    grid-column: 1/4;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin auto and set text-align to center, as below. I also added an updated snippet. BTW, you will not need justify-self and align-self, unless you are using them for some other reasons.

```
.head-content-container {
    grid-area: head;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```css
.grid-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); 
    grid-template-rows: 500px 500px 500px 500px 200px;
    grid-template-areas: "head head head"
                         "main main main"
                         "portfolio_1 portfolio_2 portfolio_3"
                         "portfolio_4 portfolio_5 portfolio_6"
                         "footer footer footer";
}

.main-header {
    grid-area: head;
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/1000/800/tech);
    background-size: cover;
    grid-column: 1/4;
    color: white;
}

.main-nav-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr); 
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #191919;
}

.nav-logo-wrapper {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    padding: .5em;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.nav-logo {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.head-content-container {
    grid-area: head;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body>
        <nav class="main-nav-wrapper">
            <div class="nav-logo-wrapper">
                <img class="nav-logo" src="img\T-Portfolio_Logo-02.svg" alt="Bolt Development Logo">
            </div>       
        </nav>
        <div class="grid-wrapper">
            <header class="main-header">
                <div class="head-content-container">
                    <h1>Bolt Development</h1>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you.  How would I vertically align it in the center as well?

Comment: Which one, you mean the label Bolt Development? You want it to be vertically aligned with respect to what? The entire container so it will be placed almost at the middle of screen?

Comment: I would like the center vertically and horizontally the "head-content-container" inside the "main-header".

Comment: Could you provide a mock screenshot so I can apply the required accordingly?

Comment: How did it go?.

Comment: I figured it out. I guess I was overthinking it and when you mentioned not using the justify and align self I realized that is more for the grid containers themselves.  Thanks for the help and checking back.  I am a real newb but enjoy figuring it out as much as the 3nd product.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your code to this:

```
.head-content-container {
    grid-area: head;
    **text-align: center;**
}
```

Or if you really want to give a width of 50%, you can add `margin: 0 auto` too it. Hope this helps!